# Multiple API calls to create object

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

Let's say, for instance, I had a class:

```
public class NI {

   private int id;
   @SerializedName("date")
   private String created_at;
   private String slug;
   private String type;
   private String link;

   private WPTitle title;

   private WPContent content;

   private WPExcerpt excerpt;
   @SerializedName("author")
   private int authorId;
   private int featured_media;
   private WPMedia media;
   List<Integer> categories;
}
```

And another class:

```
public class WPMedia {
  private int id;
  private String media_type;
  private String mime_type;
  private String source_url;
}
```

The issue is that `WPMedia` would require a separate API call based on the value of `int featured_media`. How would I build an observable chain so that it gets the `NI` class then another to get `WPMedia` then set it on the object?

I'm using Retrofit to make the API calls like this:

```
@GET("wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
Observable<ArrayList<NI>>getPostsObservableByCategory(@Query("categories") int category, @Query ("per_page") int limit, @Query("page") int skip);

@GET("wp-json/wp/v2/media/{id}")
Observable<WPMedia> getMediaObservable(@Path("id") int id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not yet totally clear to me what you want precisely, but I'll give it a shot.

An assumption I do at first is that on `NI` you have a setter with signature `public void setWPMedia(WPMedia media)`. Given the two Retrofit function definitions you give, I'd say you do the following:

```
getPostsObservableByCategory(...)
  .flatMap(nis -> getMediaObservable(...)
    .first()
    .doOnNext(m -> nis.foreach(ni -> ni.setWPMedia(m)))
    .map(m -> nis));
```

Going over this line by line:

- `getPostsObservableByCategory(...)` gives you an `Observable` that emits lists of `NI` instances. The `media` field on each `NI` in these lists may or may not be set already.
- `getMediaObservable(...)` gets the `WPMedia` instance that needs to be set on **each** element in the corresponding list.
- I limit the number of emissions of `getMediaObservable` to one, otherwise the field in `NI` will be set multiple times, which I presume is not really desirable. You can omit this line if this is already guaranteed by the `getMediaObservable(...)` function/implementation.
- setting a field is considered a side-effect, so we need the `doOnNext` here, in which we loop over the list of `NI` instances and set the `WPMedia` field to the one gotten from `getMediaObservable`.
- I assume you want to have the list of `NI` instances afterwards, so I added a `map` that just replaces the `m` with that list.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: The NI class needs to be loaded first so that the feature_media int can be available and then it is passed to the getMediaObservable call. If I understand your example correctly, I don't see how the said int is passed to the getMediaObservable  call. I'm I being clear?

Comment: Ah, in that case it should probably be something like the following: `getPostsObservableByCategory(...).flatMap(nis -> Observable.from(nis).flatMap(ni -> getMediaObservable(ni.getFeatureMedia).first().doOnNext(ni::setWPMedia).map(m -> ni)))`. You put the list `nis` in an `Observable` and `flatMap` over each element, while calling `getMediaObservable` with the `featureMedia` field (via a getter) from each `ni`.

Comment: I'm getting an "Inference variable R has incompatible bounds" compile error from .map(m -> ni)

Comment: Maybe you should add `<NI>` between the `.` and `map`? Most likely the compiler can't infer the types by itself. Just to be clear, I haven't tested nor compiled this myself. This is just to give you an idea of how this might work!

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Now I understand streams a little better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I find a demo for you !!! I think you can do like below:

```
@GET("/token")
public Observable<String> getToken();

@GET("/user")
public Observable<User> getUser(@Query("token") String token, @Query("userId") String userId);

...

getToken()
.flatMap(new Func1<String, Observable<User>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<User> onNext(String token) {
        return getUser(token, userId);
    })
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(new Observer<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(User user) {
        userView.setUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable error) {
        // Error handling
        ...
    }
});
```

[Blog Link](http://gank.io/post/560e15be2dca930e00da1083#toc_26)